# Application should load content from database but doesn't

Tags: android, database, assets

I have a very annoying problem and I can't seem to find a way to fix it. I made a first application (a beta version just to test my methods) in which I defined everything, so my application could communicate with a database. It worked perfectly.

I started my new application on the very same model, keeping the same classes and everything but it doesn't work anymore. For example, I am supposed to open a listview which has to display some content from database : I can open the listview (there is no crash of my app when I do so) but it's just empty.

One of the difference with my beta application is the size of the database : it's now 4 mo instead of a few ko. I have read some things about the size of databases stored in assets file, but one previous version I could make my application work with the same database.
Also, my logcat doesn't tell me anything : I just have my app working fine but not displaying any of the things it's supposed to.

Here is my code (if I may, I feel like my code is very light compared to what I usually read on internet with loads of catch/try/exception/various classes, etc. so maybe it's juts the strictly required code with no extra but it was working for my beta version):

**A/ DatabaseAdapter** (my method getting data from the database is defined at the end and called findPoiInTable):

```
public class DatabaseAdapter {

public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "tblpoisurvey";

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String COL_NAME = "name";
public static final String COL_CAT1 = "cat1";
public static final String COL_CAT2 = "cat2";
public static final String COL_CAT3 = "cat3";
public static final String COL_SUBCAT = "subcat";
public static final String COL_STREET = "street";

private Context myContext;
private SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;
private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
private Cursor c;

// Constructor
public DatabaseAdapter(Context context) {
    this.myContext = context;
}

public DatabaseAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(myContext);
    try {
        dbHelper.createDatabase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    myDatabase = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    return this;
}


public void close() {
    if (c != null) {
        c.close();
    }
    try {
        dbHelper.close();
        myDatabase.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public Cursor findPoiInTable(String inInterval) {
    String where = COL_CAT1 + " IN " + inInterval + " OR " + COL_CAT2
            + " IN " + inInterval + " OR " + COL_CAT3 + " IN " + inInterval;

    Cursor c = myDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID,
            COL_NAME, COL_STREET }, where, null, null, null, null);
    return c;
} }
```

**B/ My ResultListViewActivity**, the one calling the method, getting the input for this method from another activity via getExtra and displaying the result in a listview.

```
public class ResultListViewActivity extends Base_Activity {

private SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
private DatabaseAdapter dbHelper;
ListView listView;
TextView poititle; 
private static String TAG = ResultListViewActivity.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result_list_view);

    poititle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.poititle);
    dbHelper = new DatabaseAdapter(this);
    dbHelper.open();

    displayListView();
}

private void displayListView() {

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String title = bundle.getString("title", "Choose here :");  
    String inInterval = bundle.getString("inInterval");

    poititle.setText(title); // FYI: the title is displayed properly so the problem is not from the putExtra / getExtra

    Cursor c = dbHelper.findPoiInTable(inInterval);
    String[] columns = new String[] {DatabaseAdapter.COL_NAME,
            DatabaseAdapter.COL_STREET };

    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.name, R.id.street};

    cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.poi_info, c, columns, to, 0);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.poilistview);
    listView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);         
    }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}  }
```

**C/** I don't think this is gonna be useful but in case of, my **DatabaseHelper class** :

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static String DB_NAME = "POIfinal";
private static int DB_VERSION = 1;
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.asiatypeapplicationbeta/databases/";
private static String TAG = DatabaseHelper.class.getSimpleName();

private SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;
private Context myContext;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    this.myContext = context ;
}

public void createDatabase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDatabase();
    if (!dbExist) {

        // By calling this method and empty database will be created into
        // the default system path
        // of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that
        // database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDatabase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Check if the database already exists to avoid re-copying the file each
 * time you open the application.
 * 
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDatabase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        final String message = e.getMessage();
        return false;
    }
    checkDB.close();
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
 * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
 * handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */

private void copyDatabase() throws IOException {
    // open the LOCAL DATABASE as the INPUT stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    // path to the just created empty db
    String outfilename = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    // open the EMPTY DATABASE as the OUTPUT stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outfilename);

    // transfer bytes from the INPUTfile to the OUTPUTfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}

public void openDatabase() throws SQLException {
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    try {
        myDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        final String message = e.getMessage();
        if (message == null) {
            throw e;
        }
        if (!message.contains("attempt to write a readonly database")) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() throws SQLException {

    if (myDatabase != null)
        try {
            myDatabase.close();
            super.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {

        }

}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
       Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
               + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
       db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notes");
       onCreate(db);
}  }
```

Edit: picture of my logcat with an error message, only the first time I run my application (after uninstalling it for example).
[image]

Comment: How are you accessing the data in the database? One issue is that, if you're loading the database on the main thread, you'll block the UI until everything is loaded, so it'll look empty until it has finished loading. Try tapping the screen once the app has loaded and see if you get an "Activity Not Responding" dialog after a few seconds.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the issue as I can still click my action bar for example, and nothing appears even after a while. When I click on my MainActivity buttons, it actually call a method selecting elements from my database where Column_AA = something. Actually I don't even know what to do to fix this, everything is helpless: logcat empty, application working fine (but empty), nothing underlined in red and no error message. It looks like everything is fine even if it's not at all...

Comment: Hmm, well in that case it might be helpful for you to post your code, it just sounds like a very small thing is missing.

Comment: Check if the cursor returned for displaying the listview. Is moveToFirst() false or true?

Comment: @Espiandev : I just edited and added some code to make it more clear, thanks for your concern!

Comment: @HoanNguyen : I added this code in my displayListView() to check and it returned false for (cursor.moveToFirst()). Code: boolean result = c.moveToFirst();

  Context context = getApplicationContext();
  CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
  int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

  Toast.makeText(context, "debug:" + result , duration).show();

Comment: That means that whatever you query from the database return no rows.

Comment: That is there is no record in your database that has COL_CAT1 = any of the value in the inInterval and same for COL_CAT2 and COL_CAT3. To test that your query is correct you should pass in some values in the inInterval that you know for sure exist in the database.

Comment: Put a log after the line String inInterval = bundle.getString("inInterval"); Log.d(TAG, "inInterval = " + inInterval); and check your logcat to see if the inInterval has correct values.

Comment: @HoanNguyen : I checked, the inInterval has correct values and the database has fitting values in its cat1, cat2 or cat3. So weird. I also tried to uninstall everything, delete the database and install it again and I had this interesting thing: when I first run the application on the device, I have something in my logcat saying that it failed to open the database. But then when I modify my code and re-run it again, logcat is empty : the error message is ONLY for the first run. (picture of my logcat in my edited first post)

Comment: What code do you modify? did you update your code above?

Comment: The code above is the one I am using right now and have a problem with. Actually, in my beta version it was the same DatabaseHelper, the same methods, I just changed the variables names and use a different database. So the problem must definitely connecting to the database but as the code is the same as the one which works for my beta application, it gives me headache... By the way, I'm not using things I have read are important (cursors.close() for example), but neither did I in my beta. Could it be a problem with a bigger database?

Comment: do you run on a phone connected to the computer?

Comment: Yes I do, I haved never tried it on an emulator so far.

Comment: Ok, run your app again, then unplug from the computer. Clear your data through the Manage apps or System settings menu and then run your app again (unpluged from the computer). Your phone may not be able to access the file while plug in through the USB

Comment: Just tried, still the same results. I feel like it takes some time to try to open the empty listview Activity though, like if there was a small load. (although i'm not so sure, it's about less than half a second)

Comment: But your cursor is empty so there is nothing to load, the time it takes maybe from trying to create the database. Are you sure the database that you try to copy is not empty.

Comment: No the database isn't empty, it's actually a >4mo file so much bigger than the one in my beta version.

Comment: So when you clear everything, and run plug in the computer you get an exception in the logcat and the app force close isn't it?

Comment: When I keep plugged and then from Manage Apps I clear data and force stop and then start again my app, it doesn't close. It's the same as usual : empty listview. But in my Logcat i have the same lines as what I edited in my first post saying it failed to open the database.

Comment: Ok the first time that is what it suppose to be because there is no database there. And then you have the code to copy. Let me look real close at that code.

Comment: Clear your data again and put a log inside if (!dbExist) statement Log.d(TAG, "dbExist is false");

Comment: Ok, thanks again for taking time to help !

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26074/discussion-between-hoan-nguyen-and-phalanx)

Comment: Just click on the continue this discussion in chat above when you are ready.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your Database Helper class I think you are trying to copy the database from your assets folder.

So before opening your database by  dbHelper.open(); try first copying it to your internal path. The method createdatabase in your Databasehelper class will copy it to internal location...Then try to open it. Right now what might be happening is that your open() method cannot find the database at the given path.

Also try to pass your database name with its extension like "somedatabase.sqlite" if there is any.